# How to get JSON object in jQuery's ajaxError?

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I want to create a global ajax error handler using the jQuery ajaxError() handler, such as this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    alert('error in: ' + settings.url + ' \\n'+'error:\\n' + exception);
});
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

But I want to expand on this by having the server return a JSON object instead of just text, and then my error handler can use properties of the object to decide what to do and to make a nice error dialog. But how do I do this?

I now have the server returning a valid JSON formatted string but I am used to the jQuery function having a "data' parameter which is automatically parsed for me, how do I do this using the ajaxError function which does not have such a 'data' parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the responseText of the xhr object: `xhr.responseText`. You may need to parse this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom properties to the settings object when setting up the ajax request. When the ajaxError function is invoked, just check the incoming settings object for the custom properties you added and use them as needed.